# What conditions should vector $x$ satisfy so that $\|[x_2+\alpha x_1, \dots, x_n + \alpha x_1]\|_2$ is bounded by a constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose that $x = [x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is a vector with norm less than or equal to one $\|x\|_2^2 \leq 1$. Let $\alpha \in [0,1]$ and define the following vector

$$y = [x_2+\alpha x_1, \dots, x_n + \alpha x_1]$$

How can I find a non-trivial subset of $x$ that, regardless of the value of $\alpha$, would result in $\|y\|_2^2 \leq C$ where $C$ is a constant that does not depend on $n$?

The above is satisfied when $x_1 = \dots = x_n$. For example, if $x = [1/\sqrt{n}, \dots, 1/\sqrt{n}]$ then, we have $\|y\|^2_2 = \frac{(1+\alpha)^2}{n} \times n  = (1+\alpha)^2 \leq 4$. But I'm looking for a larger subset (or all $x$ that satisfy the above conditions) than $x_1 = \dots = x_n$.

Comment: Is $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?

Comment: @Botond Yes, $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the condition $|x_1|\le 1/\sqrt n$ and you get $\|y\|^2\le 4$. In fact,
$$
\|y\|^2 = [(n-1)\alpha - 1 -2\alpha]   x_1^2 + \sum x_1^2 + 2\alpha x_1\sum x_i 
$$
but 
$$
\sum x_i \le n\sqrt{\sum x_i^2/n}\le \sqrt n
$$
so
$$
\|y\|^2 \le [(n-3)\alpha - 1 ]   x_1^2 + 1 + 2\alpha x_1\sqrt n \le 4
$$

Comment: Is it also true that if $x_1 > 1/\sqrt{n}$, then it is impossible that $\|y\|^2 \leq C$?

Comment: actually, if $x_1\le s/\sqrt n$ with $s>1$, then with the same reasoning, $\|y\|^2\le 4s^2$